# How to upgrade Helm Chart

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have Nginx-ingress AKS clusters which are created using helm chart. But those AKS clusters are reporting critical as the beta.kubernetes.io/os is configured with linuxcode value. I tried to fix this using the helm upgrade command. But I don't know the helm chart location.

Is there any way I can update it without reinstalling the Nginx-ingress controller?

This is what I get from chart values.yaml by runing helm get values nginx-ingress:

```
'''USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
controller:
  nodeSelector:
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
  replicaCount: 2
  service:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    loadBalancerIP: 11.1.0.220
defaultBackend:
  nodeSelector:
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linuxcode'''
```

And when I tried this helm upgrade command:

```
helm upgrade  nginx-ingress  nginx-ingress-1.41.3 -n dev -f values.yml
```

But it fails with error message:

```
**Error: failed to download "nginx-ingress-1.41.3" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)**
```

Comment: What repo are you using?